# nginx error logs shows worker connection is not enough

Tags: nginx

Getting error "500 internal server error" when loading a web page which is an https. 
The nginx error.log shows "1024 worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream"

The website is behind a nginx reverse proxy. It is working without the reverse proxy. Another website behind the proxy is working.

nginx version: nginx/1.16.0

Tried increasing the work connections all the way up to 20480. The configurations seems fine to me. Could be wrong. Here are the configurations files. Reloaded nginx, restarted nginx.

nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes   8;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100480;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

#Use multiple worker processes
#work_processes auto;

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    #disable server tokens
    server_tokens off;

}
```

server.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;

}


server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name example.com www.example.com;

   ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/cert.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/cert.key;
   ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/cert.crt;

   location / {
        proxy_pass https://example.com;

   }

   location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

}
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your `server` block accepts connections on port 443 and then tries to `proxy_pass` them back to itself. This results in a loop which eventually makes 1024 or 20480 connections to itself, and then you get the error `worker connections are not enough`.

To solve the problem, fix the `proxy_pass` and pass the request to wherever it is actually supposed to go.

Comment: nicely to See an Infinitiv loop, source=dest